# Copy multiple columns from multiple worksheets to new workbook and filter by date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to solve a problem with some data sorting and despite quite a few attempts trying solutions suggested by the forum I'm not getting very far.

I have a workbook with 20+ worksheets in. I want to copy about 4 columns (B, C, E and L) from row 5 onwards in to a new workbook (on just one sheet). Its the same columns on each of the 20+ sheets. Not all columns in each row hold data and its important when these copy they remain blank. Some sheets in the original workbook contain just a couple of rows, some hundreds - rows of data are always bring added.

Assuming I can find a way to automate the copying of this in to a new workbook I would only want to pull through the rows in which column L had the letter 'Y' in.

Column C is a date and in an ideal world I would be able to dicatate only dates after a specific date that pull through from the original to the new workbook.

Again, this is because the data in the original workbook is being continuously added to but I only need to report out of the new workbook sporadically.

I feel like this should be easier than I am making it....but maybe not!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use either the VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP functions in excel so that you can extract the data from the other worksheets.
The following links might be of assistance:

1. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f
2. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1